# Помогите найти ошибку. Пытаюсь собрать проект с помощью parceljs, вылетает ошибка

Tags: javascript

```
C:\Users\79663\Desktop\learn\learn\constructor\src\styles\main.css:undefined:undefined: plugin is not a function
    at LazyResult.run (C:\Users\79663\Desktop\learn\learn\constructor\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:288:14)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\79663\Desktop\learn\learn\constructor\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:212:26)
    at C:\Users\79663\Desktop\learn\learn\constructor\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:254:14  
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at LazyResult.async (C:\Users\79663\Desktop\learn\learn\constructor\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:250:23)
    at LazyResult.then (C:\Users\79663\Desktop\learn\learn\constructor\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:131:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! constructor@1.0.0 build: `parcel build ./src/index.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the constructor@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\79663\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-08T09_54_02_169Z-debug.log
```

Как написан скрипт в json

```json
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "parcel ./src/index.html -p 4200 --open",
    "build": "parcel build ./src/index.html"
  },
```

Импорт css в index.js

```
    import '../styles/main.css'
```

[image: ошибка в консоли и структура проекта]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогли эти две команды в консоли, чтобы исправить ошибку.

```
npm uninstall cssnano
npm i -D cssnano@4.1.11
```